# Accessing generics from inherited type

Tags: typescript

I am trying to access generics from another class, which will be passed as a generic itself.

```
export default abstract class Foo<K, V> {}
```

```
import Foo from './Foo';
export default abstract class Bar<Foo> {}
```

How would I go about accessing the `K` and `V` within `Bar` class? I would like to create an abstract method that uses these types, but I'm not sure how I would actually access the nested generic.

**Edit:** Added use case for more clarification

Example use case:

```
export default class Baz extends Foo<string, number> {}
```

```
import Baz from './Baz';
export default class Qux extends Bar<Baz> {}
```

I would like the `Bar` class to recognise that `Qux` should hold the generics `<string, number>`, as I want to have an abstract method within `Bar` that follows the signature

```
public abstract foo(thing: string): number;
```

as an example.

An alternative that I have considered: passing `Baz` within the `constructor` instead of as a generic type... However, there still is an issue of actually getting the generic types from the `Baz` itself.

**Edit 2:** Actual use-case

Okay, so I have these 2 classes.

```
export default abstract class Storage<K, V> {
    protected abstract _init(): void;
}
```

```
import Data from '../structures/bases/Data';
export default class DataStore extends Storage<string, Data> {
    protected async _init(): void {
        // ...
    }
}
```

Here's where the issues comes in

```
import Data from '../structures/bases/Data';
export default class DataHandler extends Handler<DataStore> {
    public abstract get(key: string): Data {
        //...
    }
}
```

```
export default abstract class Handler<K, V> {
    // my goal, where K is string and V is Data when DataStore is passed
    public abstract get(key: K): V;
}
```

I am going to have several `*Handler`s where I would pass an instance of an extended `Storage` as the generic. Now obviously I can't magically plug in `K` and `V`, what I can do instead I suppose is have `Handler<K, V>` and then pass `<string, Command>`, but I was hoping that I could simply pass the instance of *Storage instead of passing the 2 types again everytime.

Comment: I am not sure what you mean by "accessing" `K`, and `V` from Bar. Inside of Bar, you can reference the unbound type variables K and V. And inside of Qux, K and V will be bound to `string` and `number` respectively. Can you add a more complete example that illustrates the problem exactly? Preferably something with a compile error, but that explains what you are trying to do.

Comment: @AndrewEisenberg Sorry for the confusion, I have made another edit.

Answer (score 2):

Your definition of `Bar` is incorrect. It should look something like this:

```
import Foo from './Foo';
export default abstract class Bar<K, V, F extends Foo<K,V>> {}
```

Your original `Foo` was a type variable inside of bar and *not* the `Foo` class you want it to be. And then `K` and `V` are bound to the type variables of the instance of Foo. And now, all of the type variables are available in your `Bar` instance

This is a bit of a monster, but using type variables can quickly get out of hand.

Comment: I'm having trouble understanding why this is correct. Wouldn't this allow for something like `const bar = new Bar<string, number, Foo<string, string>>();`?

Comment: @tomcek112 Only if `Foo<string, string>` extends `Foo<string, number>`, which it probably shouldn't.  (In the example, `Foo<K, V>` is literally an [empty class](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/FAQ#why-do-these-empty-classes-behave-strangely) with [unused type parameters](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/FAQ#why-is-astring-assignable-to-anumber-for-interface-at--), both of which are bad practice in TypeScript.)

Comment: @AndrewEisenberg sometimes I've used things like `Bar<F extends Foo<any, any>>` and then if I need `K` and `V` I use conditional types like `type K<F extends Foo<any, any>> = F extends Foo<infer K, any> ? K : never` and `type V<F extends foo<any, any>> = F extends Foo<any, infer V> ? V : never`.

Comment: Please see the edit, apologies for not clarifying this beforehand.

Comment: Now, I'm not clear what you are asking, so see my comment above.